# SQL Transaction log backup fails due to login delay (error code: 0x80004005)

Tags: sql-server

**Problem:**
My transaction log backup in my Maintenance Plan which runs every 15 minutes fails intermittently with the error below:

[image]

**System:**

MS SQL 2016 node running on AWS EC2
System authenticate against a local DC and DNS that sits on the same subnet.

**What I've tried:**

- I tested the ping (ping -t SERVER_NAME) when this issue occurred, my
  ping response was less than 1ms and 0 packet loss.
- I am able to
  connect to SSMS without any issue when using
  SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME.
- When I run nslookup SERVER_NAME, it resolves to proper IP.
- All my OS firewall is off.
- Set the order of
  all enabled protocol as (Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes)
- I
  changed the connection timeout from default 600s to 1100.  However,
  the log shows this timeout occurs after only 21 seconds.

When I look at the event log on my SQL node I see the following error which occurs upon each failure to backup a transaction log.

[image]

I don't really understand what this error really mean? is it a case where my sql service account is missing certain permission? if so that does not make sense because it should not work period whereas right now this issue is intermittent.

I want to post it here hoping you can point me if I should look into specific area such as permission, networking, ect...?

Comment: hi! here's something really odd, unless i'm misreading or missing an important detail.  the event viewer entry from 3:15:01 pm seems to follow a *successful* run rather than one that produced an error in the log file summary?

Comment: @sqL_handLe I begun to think this error is not related to my issue.  I googled it and it shows this error often indicate the SSIS user does not have certain permission.

Comment: internittent failures are a killer. is MPP (memory pressure protection) enabled on the system?

Comment: @sqL_handLe I don't know what that is so I don't think it is enabled? however resource is not an issue at this moment because my node is not live yet.  It has 32 core and 256GB of memory.  At any given item I'm the only one logging in and CPU and memory usage are less than 5% at all time.

Comment: actually, unless you’ve disabled it, it’s probably enabled. and it could cause havoc. because if SQLAgent is performing the tasks - you *and* SQLAgent are both logging in. and it’s not exactly a total resources thing. MPP responds to “bursts” which are ever only vaguely described. here’s one article… https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/understand-memory-pressure-protection

Comment: and another article follows. with enough investigation, a different intermittent error cause should leave breadcrumbs somewhere. But MPP is a heartbreaker because it leaves no breadcrumbs, can cause initial connection failure or failure of an established connection at its discretion with no logging afaik. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-new-memory-pressure-protection-feature-for-tcp-stack-749c1746-ba10-ec18-d61a-bbdabbc403fc

Comment: This smells like a DNS problem... but I see you've tried other ways to connect, so then I need to ask: what else is running at the same time on that box? We're talking all the way up and down the stack. I've only seen this with a) DNS or misconfigured networking; or b) the box is actually too busy to let anyone log in. How high is the CPU load at those intermittent times? Etc.

Comment: It is @RandolphWest , I think I found the solution.  I'm just taking sometime to test it out and verify that is indeed the root cause and I'll post my answer.